# Array and ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have some questions about `Array` and `ArrayList`. I have searched here and could not find precisely the answers i am looking for.

1. I understand `Arrays` and `ArrayList` are part of `java.util`. So when I create and `Array` or `ArrayList` am I creating objects and instances?
2. Why must the `java.util.ArraList` be imported to create an `ArrayList` object but there is no need to import `java.util.Arrays` to create and Array object?
3. Why are the methods of Array called in a different manner than those of `ArrayList`? Is it because the methods of Arrays class are all static?
4. Why it is said that the performance of using and Array is faster than the performance of using an `ArrayList`?
5. I understand that to iterate values in an Array a for loop could be used. What about to iterate values in `ArrayList` - I understand that a for loop can also be used but in the Internet it is said that I could use an iterator, what would be this iterator?
6. Can an Array be multidimensional if it is storing objects?
7. If I am working with primitive data then i understand they should all be stored in an array, since `ArrayList` cannot contain primitive data types. But if I am working only with objects, should I choose to work with `Array` or `ArrayList`?

Comment: Pretty sure there a tons of answers to all those questions.

Comment: As a first hint: `java.util.Arrays` is just a util class to handle _real_ arrays. This class is not an array.

Comment: You are confusing `Array` with `Arrays`.

Comment: I purpose that you divide your question into multie topics.

Comment: Please ask [one question per post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).

Comment: Some of this knowledge is required to get you started in programming, but some of your questions cannot be answered without going in extreme detail to a point where this knowledge is irrelevant for you at this stage. It's better to just accept some things and your understanding will grow as you go along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you create an array or `ArrayList` you are creating an instance/object.

Packages are like directories containing Class definitions (e.g. the `java.util` package contains the `ArrayList` class). All classes within a package have a unique name. But **class names can be reused in other packages**. So, there is actually more than 1 ArrayList class possible.
So, that's why **the java compiler always needs to know the full name of the class**.

So, when you are creating an `ArrayList` you want the compiler to know that you are creating a `java.util.ArrayList`. You could actually specify that during your object creation:

```
java.util.ArrayList list = new java.util.ArrayList();
```

But that's really **verbose**. It's annoying that you would have to repeat this full name all the time. That's what the `import` statements are for. **By specifying an `import java.util.ArrayList` you are telling the compiler that all references to `ArrayList` are in fact of type `java.util.ArrayList`**.

Arrays are really special classes. They are not primitives, but there's a lot happening underneath the hood of the java virtual machine and compiler. Honestly, I don't want to explain too much about this, because it would just confuse you.

But in short, java uses a dedicated class for each type of array. So, there's a `int[]` class, a `long[]` class, an `Object[]` class etc.

Honestly **the performance of an array is not better than the one of an `ArrayList`**. Both have their strong points.

An `Iterator` is something that was invented before for-each iterations were introduced in java. You can only use iterator for collections that implement the `Iterable` interface. (Again, not the case for arrays). One of the advantages of iterators, is that you can remove objects from a list while iterating (ie using the `iterator.remove()` method)

Sure, an array can be multidimensional, even if it stores objects. And indeed **an `ArrayList` cannot contain primitive types**.

I usually **prefer the use of an `ArrayList`**. One of the main advantages of an `ArrayList`, is that it automatically resizes when it's capacity is exceeded. That's not the case for an array.

On the other hand, **if you know the exact length of your list, then an array will use less memory.**

Just to be complete: there is also an `Arrays` class which contains the convenience methods that are missing on the array instances. Indeed, those methods are strictly static methods.

Comment: Also very nice answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest manner, hand-waving past the details:

An array (note the small-a name) is a fixed size aggregate type; it is not something that can be classed. An ArrayList is part of the Collections framework. See the Javadocs for details on what this collection offers.

java.util.Arrays is a convenience class that provides *static* methods useful for manipulating arrays. Since they are static, there is no direct instantiation required or allowed.

Your other questions need to be adjusted once you get past these fundamentals.

Comment: Ah I see now. You could understand my real doubts and point me towards the right direction. I can see you are very knowledgeable! :-). Bye.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `ArrayList` is one of the collections available in the Java collections library. You create an `ArrayList` object which lets you manage a sequence of items. On the other hand, `Arrays` is a collection of utility functions that operate on arrays. You create a new array by doing something like `new int[10]`.
2. You construct an `ArrayList` with `new ArrayList()`, thus you must import it. The `Arrays` class has nothing to do with creating arrays and is thus not required.
3. `Arrays` and `ArrayList` are entirely different. One is just a collection of functions (which are not methods of the array) and you cannot create an instance of `Arrays`. The methods of `ArrayList` directly operate on the `ArrayList`.
4. An array provides direct access to array storage and holds values of any type (primitives and object references), while an `ArrayList` van only hold object references. For object references, there is no real speed difference, but for primitives, the values must be put into and taken out of an object "box", which is substantially slower.
5. An iterator is an object which implements traversal of a collection, letting you get the next item (`next`) and allows you to ask if there are any more (`hasNext`) in the most efficient way possible for the type of collection. Iterators are also used in loops, but are safer because you don't have to manage indexes yourself.
6. Yes. An `ArrayList` is also an object, so a multidimensional `ArrayList` is just an `ArrayList` which holds `ArrayList`s.
7. If working with arrays of objects, always use `ArrayList`. It is far easier to work with (for example, if you add to an `ArrayList`, it will seamlessly reallocate the array) and it is safer. With generics, you can guarantee the right type of objects are added. With arrays, you can cast `String[]` to `Object[]`, but an `ArrayList<String>` cannot be cast to ArrayList`, making it impossible to put a`Double`into a`String` array.

Comment: Very complete answer! Thanks!